# MVC 2 - How to set the namespace targeted by an actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

I have 2 namespaces for my controllers.  One is the default MyProject.Controllers and the second is MyProject.Controllers.Framed.  I am using namespaces so that I can have a url like /home/index serve up the normal home website and /framed/home/index serves up a version intended for use in an iframe.

My problem is that when I put `<%: Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%>` in my view, it defaults to /Framed/Home/Index.  I believe this is because the framed namespace is added first in my routing and it is found first.  That's to be expected and desired.

My problem is how to I set the namespace used in my actionlink?  Ideally I'd like my website to default all actionlinks to the default namespace (MyProject.Controllers).  I'm beginning to wonder if the convenience of putting /framed in the url to change the rendering is worth all this hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx) method that provides a way to specify the route to be used:

```
<%: Html.RouteLink("FramedRouteName", new { controller: "Home", action: "Index" }) %>
```